# laravel how to display flash message with confirm message

Tags: php, laravel

hi i'm trying to display flash message with confirm(like confirm alert in javascript) . i m trying this below  code its does not display flash message. please help me to resolve the problem.

```
Session::flash('flash_message', '<b>Warning!</b> Are you sure you want to delete your this event?');
        Session::flash('flash_type', 'alert-danger');
        if($event)  {
            $event->delete();
            return Redirect::to('events')->with('message', 'Event deleted successfully!');
        } else {
            Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-danger');
            return Redirect::to('events')->with('message', 'Please try again');
        }
```

Comment: How are you outputing it in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, where you have the button to delete a record for example you should have something like this:

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
@endif

{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('events.destroy', $id), 'method' => 'delete')) }}
    <button type="submit" href="{{ URL::route('events.destroy', $id) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure delete this record?')){return false;};">Delete</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

In your controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $evento = Evento::find($id);
    $evento->delete();
    Session::flash('success', 'Event delete successfully!');
    return Redirect::to('eventos');

}
```